# Google API Translate not working for Language.HINDI

Tags: java

I am attaching the code below.

```
import com.google.api.translate.Language;
import com.google.api.translate.Translate;
public class Translator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //      Translate trans = new Translate();
        try{
            System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "192.16.3.254");
            System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8080");
            Translate.setHttpReferrer("http://code.google.com/p/google-api-translate-java/");
            String translatedText = Translate.execute("How are you?", Language.ENGLISH, Language.HINDI);
            System.out.println("translated text :" + translatedText);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


}
```

This is giving output as
translated text : ?? ???? ????

but for Language.FRENCH,Language.SPANISH its giving the translated text.

Could you please tell a solution for this.

Comment: Side Note: Just in case you're unaware, the Google Translate API is becoming paid-only starting December 1st: [article](http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/v2/getting_started.html).

Answer (score 0):

If console can not display the chars correctly, it may caused by the Local Setting of the host  operation system. If the system local is set to be English, then multi-bytes characters may not be displayed correctly. You can try to write it to a file and check it using a text editor, like Notepad++. And make sure you choose the correct encoding in Notepad++ :)